# How to restart kube-proxy in Kubernetes 1.2 (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes

As of Kubernetes 1.2, kube-proxy is now a pod running in the kube-system namespace.

The old init script **/etc/init.d/kube-proxy** has been removed.

Aside from simply resetting the GCE instance, is there a good way to restart kube-proxy?

I just added an annotation to change the proxy mode, and I need to restart kube-proxy for my change to take effect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The kube-proxy is run as an addon pod, meaning the Kubelet will automatically restart it if it goes away. This means you can restart the kube-proxy pod by simply deleting it:

```
$ kubectl delete pod --namespace=kube-system kube-proxy-${NODE_NAME}
```

Where `$NODE_NAME` is the node you want to restart the proxy on (this is assuming a default configuration, otherwise `kubectl get pods --kube-system` should include the list of kube-proxy pods).

If the restarted kube-proxy is missing your annotation change, you may need to update the manifest file, usually found in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` on the node.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I was concerned that if I deleted the pod it may never come back :)

Comment: What about when they're missing ? For reasons I'd desperately need to clarify, my cluster's kube-proxy pods are missing

Comment: When i ran this it lead to k8s spinning up large number of kube-proxy pods in pending state.